# Aligning content to fit a background image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm very new to coding. I have recently been through a course in which I have learned to build Snake using vanilla JS. I am now in the process of styling it and my idea was to have a background image of a Nokia 3310 phone and align the game grid to fit the screen of the phone. I have no idea how to do this. As you can see from the code, it looks a mess! I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this or point me in the right direction :)

Many thanks in advance!

```js
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid')
const startButton = document.getElementById('start')
const scoreDisplay = document.getElementById('score')
let squares = []
let currentSnake = [2,1,0]
let direction = 1
const width = 10
let appleIndex = 0
let score = 0
let intervalTime = 1000
let speed = 0.9
let timerId = 0

function createGrid() {
    //create 100 of these elements with a for loop
    for (let i=0; i < width*width; i++) {
     //create element
    const square = document.createElement('div')
    //add styling to the element
    square.classList.add('square')
    //put the element into our grid
    grid.appendChild(square)
    //push it into a new squares array    
    squares.push(square)
    }
}
createGrid()

currentSnake.forEach(index => squares[index].classList.add('snake'))

function startGame() {
    //remove the snake
    currentSnake.forEach(index => squares[index].classList.remove('snake'))
    //remove the apple
    squares[appleIndex].classList.remove('apple')
    clearInterval(timerId)
    currentSnake = [2,1,0]
    score = 0
    //re add new score to browser
    scoreDisplay.textContent = score
    direction = 1
    intervalTime = 1000
    generateApple()
    //readd the class of snake to our new currentSnake
    currentSnake.forEach(index => squares[index].classList.add('snake'))
    timerId = setInterval(move, intervalTime)
}

function move() {
    if (
        (currentSnake[0] + width >= width*width && direction === width) || //if snake has hit bottom
        (currentSnake[0] % width === width-1 && direction === 1) || //if snake has hit right wall
        (currentSnake[0] % width === 0 && direction === -1) || //if snake has hit left wall
        (currentSnake[0] - width < 0 && direction === -width) || //if snake has hit top
        squares[currentSnake[0] + direction].classList.contains('snake')
    )
    return clearInterval(timerId)

    //remove last element from our currentSnake array
    const tail = currentSnake.pop()
    //remove styling from last element
    squares[tail].classList.remove('snake')
    //add square in direction we are heading
    currentSnake.unshift(currentSnake[0] + direction)
    //add styling so we can see it
    
    //deal with snake head gets apple
    if (squares[currentSnake[0]].classList.contains('apple')) {
        //remove the class of apple
        squares[currentSnake[0]].classList.remove('apple')
        //grow our snake by adding class of snake to it
        squares[tail].classList.add('snake')
        console.log(tail)
        //grow our snake array
        currentSnake.push(tail)
        console.log(currentSnake)
        //generate new apple
        generateApple()
        //add one to the score
        score++
        //display our score
        scoreDisplay.textContent = score
        //speed up our snake
        clearInterval(timerId)
        console.log(intervalTime)
        intervalTime = intervalTime * speed
        console.log(intervalTime)
        timerId = setInterval(move, intervalTime)
    }
    
    
    
    squares[currentSnake[0]].classList.add('snake')
}






function generateApple() {
    do {
        appleIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * squares.length)
    } while (squares[appleIndex].classList.contains('snake'))
    squares[appleIndex].classList.add('apple')
} 
generateApple()

// 39 is right arrow
// 38 is for the up arrow
// 37 is for the left arrow
// 40 is for the down arrow

function control(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 39) {
        console.log('right pressed')
        direction = 1
    } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
        console.log('up pressed')
        direction = -width
    } else if (e.keyCode === 37) {
        console.log('left pressed')
        direction = -1
    } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
        console.log('down pressed')
        direction = +width
    }
}
document.addEventListener('keyup', control)
startButton.addEventListener('click', startGame)
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 10;
    padding: 10;
    background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/D60kU6I.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto;  
}

.grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: solid 2px black;
}

.square {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.snake {
    background-color: rgb(72, 235, 99);
}

.apple {
   background-color: rgb(228, 40, 78);
   border-radius: 50%;
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: scale(1);
    animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.95);
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    }

    70% {
        transform: scale(1);
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: scale(0.95);
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Snake Game</h1>
        <button id="start">Start/Restart</button>
        <h2>Score <span id="score"></span></h2>
        <div class="grid"></div>
        <script src="snake.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this :

```js
const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");
const startButton = document.getElementById("start");
const scoreDisplay = document.getElementById("score");
let squares = [];
let currentSnake = [2, 1, 0];
let direction = 1;
const width = 10;
let appleIndex = 0;
let score = 0;
let intervalTime = 1000;
let speed = 0.9;
let timerId = 0;

function createGrid() {
  //create 100 of these elements with a for loop
  for (let i = 0; i < width * width; i++) {
    //create element
    const square = document.createElement("div");
    //add styling to the element
    square.classList.add("square");
    //put the element into our grid
    grid.appendChild(square);
    //push it into a new squares array
    squares.push(square);
  }
}
createGrid();

currentSnake.forEach(index => squares[index].classList.add("snake"));

function startGame() {
  //remove the snake
  currentSnake.forEach(index => squares[index].classList.remove("snake"));
  //remove the apple
  squares[appleIndex].classList.remove("apple");
  clearInterval(timerId);
  currentSnake = [2, 1, 0];
  score = 0;
  //re add new score to browser
  scoreDisplay.textContent = score;
  direction = 1;
  intervalTime = 1000;
  generateApple();
  //readd the class of snake to our new currentSnake
  currentSnake.forEach(index => squares[index].classList.add("snake"));
  timerId = setInterval(move, intervalTime);
}

function move() {
  if (
    (currentSnake[0] + width >= width * width && direction === width) || //if snake has hit bottom
    (currentSnake[0] % width === width - 1 && direction === 1) || //if snake has hit right wall
    (currentSnake[0] % width === 0 && direction === -1) || //if snake has hit left wall
    (currentSnake[0] - width < 0 && direction === -width) || //if snake has hit top
    squares[currentSnake[0] + direction].classList.contains("snake")
  )
    return clearInterval(timerId);

  //remove last element from our currentSnake array
  const tail = currentSnake.pop();
  //remove styling from last element
  squares[tail].classList.remove("snake");
  //add square in direction we are heading
  currentSnake.unshift(currentSnake[0] + direction);
  //add styling so we can see it

  //deal with snake head gets apple
  if (squares[currentSnake[0]].classList.contains("apple")) {
    //remove the class of apple
    squares[currentSnake[0]].classList.remove("apple");
    //grow our snake by adding class of snake to it
    squares[tail].classList.add("snake");
    console.log(tail);
    //grow our snake array
    currentSnake.push(tail);
    console.log(currentSnake);
    //generate new apple
    generateApple();
    //add one to the score
    score++;
    //display our score
    scoreDisplay.textContent = score;
    //speed up our snake
    clearInterval(timerId);
    console.log(intervalTime);
    intervalTime = intervalTime * speed;
    console.log(intervalTime);
    timerId = setInterval(move, intervalTime);
  }

  squares[currentSnake[0]].classList.add("snake");
}

function generateApple() {
  do {
    appleIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * squares.length);
  } while (squares[appleIndex].classList.contains("snake"));
  squares[appleIndex].classList.add("apple");
}
generateApple();

// 39 is right arrow
// 38 is for the up arrow
// 37 is for the left arrow
// 40 is for the down arrow

function control(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 39) {
    console.log("right pressed");
    direction = 1;
  } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
    console.log("up pressed");
    direction = -width;
  } else if (e.keyCode === 37) {
    console.log("left pressed");
    direction = -1;
  } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
    console.log("down pressed");
    direction = +width;
  }
}
document.addEventListener("keyup", control);
startButton.addEventListener("click", startGame);
```

```css
.mobile {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nokia {
  position: absolute;
  top: 190px;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  width: 555px;
  height: 383px;
  background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/kgfWbbqB/nokia3310.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.grid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 290px;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.info {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.square {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.snake {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)
}

.apple {
  background-color: rgb(228, 40, 78);
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  transform: scale(1);
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  }

  70% {
    transform: scale(1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class='mobile'>
   <div class="info">
    <h1>Snake Game</h1>
    <button id="start">Start/Restart</button>
    <h2>Score <span id="score"></span></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="grid"></div>
  <div class="nokia"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh wow! That's amazing! That is the idea of what I'm looking to do :) However, how would I put my own game grid as the screen instead of the screen in the image? It's just so I can keep the Javascript working. The grid is a square so it won't work with the screen in the background image as that is a rectangle. I'm thinking of covering the screen in the background image to be the same colour as the body of the phone and then the game grid goes over it so it looks like the screen, just square. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: @RayhaanUgharadar check my edit : you just have to choose the right image and modify the z-index (the larger value will be above the smaller one). PS : you can download my edited image.

Answer (score 0):

In the stylesheet, inside `html, body {}` put these properties:

```
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
```

Additionally, I recommend that you use classes for the CSS instead of the same html tags for the body as well.

Comment: Thanks for that! It has fixed the overlapping issue :) What I'm trying to do is align the game grid so that it appears on the background image as the phone screen so it looks like the game is being played on the phone. Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? The issue with the image overlapping was because you were calling the background image on both your `html` and `body` so I limited it just to `body`. I also added some properties to your body rule and and a `margin: 0 auto` to your grid rule. This seems to work well in 1024px media query, but it looks like you will have to adjust the `background-position` depending on which media query you are in.

```js
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid')
const startButton = document.getElementById('start')
const scoreDisplay = document.getElementById('score')
let squares = []
let currentSnake = [2,1,0]
let direction = 1
const width = 10
let appleIndex = 0
let score = 0
let intervalTime = 1000
let speed = 0.9
let timerId = 0

function createGrid() {
    //create 100 of these elements with a for loop
    for (let i=0; i < width*width; i++) {
     //create element
    const square = document.createElement('div')
    //add styling to the element
    square.classList.add('square')
    //put the element into our grid
    grid.appendChild(square)
    //push it into a new squares array    
    squares.push(square)
    }
}
createGrid()

currentSnake.forEach(index => squares[index].classList.add('snake'))

function startGame() {
    //remove the snake
    currentSnake.forEach(index => squares[index].classList.remove('snake'))
    //remove the apple
    squares[appleIndex].classList.remove('apple')
    clearInterval(timerId)
    currentSnake = [2,1,0]
    score = 0
    //re add new score to browser
    scoreDisplay.textContent = score
    direction = 1
    intervalTime = 1000
    generateApple()
    //readd the class of snake to our new currentSnake
    currentSnake.forEach(index => squares[index].classList.add('snake'))
    timerId = setInterval(move, intervalTime)
}

function move() {
    if (
        (currentSnake[0] + width >= width*width && direction === width) || //if snake has hit bottom
        (currentSnake[0] % width === width-1 && direction === 1) || //if snake has hit right wall
        (currentSnake[0] % width === 0 && direction === -1) || //if snake has hit left wall
        (currentSnake[0] - width < 0 && direction === -width) || //if snake has hit top
        squares[currentSnake[0] + direction].classList.contains('snake')
    )
    return clearInterval(timerId)

    //remove last element from our currentSnake array
    const tail = currentSnake.pop()
    //remove styling from last element
    squares[tail].classList.remove('snake')
    //add square in direction we are heading
    currentSnake.unshift(currentSnake[0] + direction)
    //add styling so we can see it
    
    //deal with snake head gets apple
    if (squares[currentSnake[0]].classList.contains('apple')) {
        //remove the class of apple
        squares[currentSnake[0]].classList.remove('apple')
        //grow our snake by adding class of snake to it
        squares[tail].classList.add('snake')
        console.log(tail)
        //grow our snake array
        currentSnake.push(tail)
        console.log(currentSnake)
        //generate new apple
        generateApple()
        //add one to the score
        score++
        //display our score
        scoreDisplay.textContent = score
        //speed up our snake
        clearInterval(timerId)
        console.log(intervalTime)
        intervalTime = intervalTime * speed
        console.log(intervalTime)
        timerId = setInterval(move, intervalTime)
    }
    
    
    
    squares[currentSnake[0]].classList.add('snake')
}






function generateApple() {
    do {
        appleIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * squares.length)
    } while (squares[appleIndex].classList.contains('snake'))
    squares[appleIndex].classList.add('apple')
} 
generateApple()

// 39 is right arrow
// 38 is for the up arrow
// 37 is for the left arrow
// 40 is for the down arrow

function control(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 39) {
        console.log('right pressed')
        direction = 1
    } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
        console.log('up pressed')
        direction = -width
    } else if (e.keyCode === 37) {
        console.log('left pressed')
        direction = -1
    } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
        console.log('down pressed')
        direction = +width
    }
}
document.addEventListener('keyup', control)
startButton.addEventListener('click', startGame)
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
   
    background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/D60kU6I.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;  
    background-position: center 20%;
 
}


.grid {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: solid 2px black;
}

.square {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.snake {
    background-color: rgb(72, 235, 99);
}

.apple {
   background-color: rgb(228, 40, 78);
   border-radius: 50%;
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: scale(1);
    animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.95);
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    }

    70% {
        transform: scale(1);
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: scale(0.95);
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
```

```html
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Snake Game</h1>
        <button id="start">Start/Restart</button>
        <h2>Score <span id="score"></span></h2>
        <div class="grid"></div>
        <script src="snake.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the closest! :) I want the game grid to replace the screen on the background image. I will edit the photo in photoshop to fill the screen as the same colour as the phone. I can then align the game grid and make this appear as the phone screen. I'm still learning responsive design so I hope to learn to make it work :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to upvote or mark answered if you are happy with the result.